# A question on injective map of line bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve. Let $L_1$ be a fixed line bundle on $C$ having positive degree. If we consider the map $\text{Pic}^d(C) \to \text{Pic}^{d'}(C)$ given by $L \mapsto L \otimes L_1$, then set theoretically it's an injective map. Is it also an injective morphism?

Do we need to impose some more hypothesis so that this becomes an injective morphism?

Here  $\text{Pic}^{i}(C)$ is the moduli space parametrizing all degree $i$ line bundles over $C$.

Any argument is appreciated.

Comment: By injective morphism do you mean monomorphism? Injectivity it defined at the level of underlying topological spaces I think.

Comment: This is an isomorphism (with the inverse given by tensor product with $L_1^{-1}$).

Comment: @Sasha, yes between two Picard it's an isomorphism. But suppose if we define/ restrict the map from a zariski open dense subset of the source moduli space, then it's only injective right? My question is whether this an injective morphism so that we can compare dimension( e.g. if the restricted map is an injective morphism, then we can say the dimension of the source= dimension of the image of the morphism.)

Comment: If you restrict an isomorphism to an open subset, you obtain an isomorphism of this subset onto its image.

Comment: @Sasha, thanks. Is it true that the entire discussion also remains valid when the map is $ L \mapsto L^* \otimes L_1$ and it's known that the degree of $L_1$ is strictly bigger than  degree of each line bundle of the source space( because  line bundles have unique dual)?

Comment: Of course. And the degree doesn't matter.